# creating (rainbow) color palette

Tags: ios, colors

I want to create a color palette (with colors seen below in the image) dynamically by using the UIColor (iOS) class.
[color palette](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na27o.png)

Unfortunately I don't have many experience by using color spaces. Does anybody have an idea how I could do this?

thx and cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something very similar. I've got my rainbow image, then detect the touch events and find the color of the spot where the person touched.

And being lazy I used someone else's code!

Mark Johnson wrote this [`UIImageView` sub class](https://github.com/IceMupppet/iOS-SAMPLE-colorpicker_from_image_pixel/blob/master/Classes/ColorPickerImageView.m) which lets capture the color of an image for touch events. Just stick it your view hierarchy and set the image. Then set a callback with something like

```
[self.colorMapImageView addSelectedColorChangedListener:@selector(handleColorSelectionAction:) inObject:self];

// and then capture the data
- (void)handleColorSelectionAction:(UIColor *)color {
    NSLog(@"new color picked");
    self.selectedColor = color;
}
```